# Elegant way of authentication according to my user.status field in Spring Security

Tags: authentication, spring-security

I can authenticate user with

```
Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(this.username, this.password);
            Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

Now i must select users whose user.status field is 'active'.

I think i can put some lines before above code those check the status field,

but i also think if i can make Spring Security do it for me it is more elegant and tidy.

But i do not know how can i make SS do it for me, by overriding some classes or some methods?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77792964/6792588) worked for me on Spring-boot 3.x (and Spring Security 6.x)

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two statuses ('active', 'inactive') then instead of custom user.status fielad you can use native **user.enabled** field. This field will be checked automatically by AuthenticationManager.authenticate() method (if you use some native AuthenticationProvider like DaoAuthenticationProvider). See **enabled** attribute in [standard User Schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/appendix-schema.html#d0e8380)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following SpEL to your intercept url in your spring security configuration.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated() and principal.status == 'active'/>
```